# error: sql.h: A file or directory in the path name does not exist

Tags: c, sql-server, linux

I am trying to compile a simple C program on an UNIX machine which just has sql.h header statement to make sure that odbc headers are working.

But Im keep on getting this error.

error: sql.h: A file or directory in the path name does not exist

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sql.h>

main(){

}
```

I used this code because no matter what I put inside the Main fuction, the header itself fails.

But I have installed ODBCUnix .
Here are the commands which shows ODBC status.

> /apps/rmb/scripts$odbcinst --version
>   unixODBC 2.3.0
>
> odbcinst -j
>   unixODBC 2.3.0
>   DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
>   SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
>   FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
>   USER DATA SOURCES..: /etc/odbc.ini
>   SQLULEN Size.......: 8
>   SQLLEN Size........: 8
>   SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8

Please advise how to compile this simple program .

Comment: Have you checked this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447386/sql-h-header-file-missing-though-unixodbc-is-installed

Comment: I checked that...  It Is asking to install dev package. Is there any way to find whether it is already Installed or not because I'm using production server

Comment: So where actually **is** `sql.h` located? Doing a `find / -name sql.h` what do you get?

Comment: OT: It's `int main(void)` at least.

Comment: The command shows the following outputs 

/apps/rmb/scripts$find / -name sql.h
find: 0652-081 cannot change directory to </.cpan>:
  : The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.
find: 0652-081 cannot change directory to </.emacs.d>:
  : The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.
find: 0652-081 cannot change directory to </.pgp>:
  : The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.
find: 0652-081 cannot change directory to </.ssh>:

Comment: Hi Alk, 
I found sql.h

Now please help me how to use this to compile my C program

Comment: /usr/local/easysoft/unixODBC/include$ls
odbcinst.h       odbcinstext.h    sql.h            sqlext.h         sqltypes.h       sqlucode.h       unixodbc_conf.h

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be not formatted properly. I tried to do it again and again but it still shows the same thing.

Actually the headers were sql.h and stdio.h and a empty main program.

Please don't think like the program has typo errors. It is not formatted properly.