# sql.h not found when installing PyODBC on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, pyodbc

I'm trying to install PyODBC on Heroku, but I get `fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory` in the logs when pip runs.  How do I fix this error?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work on Heroku?

Comment: @cph  This project currently works on Heroku with such a setup https://github.com/bmwant/pr-review-notifier

Answer (score 179):

To follow up on the answer below...

Example for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev
```

Example for CentOS:

```
sudo yum install unixODBC-devel
```

Example for Fedora:

```
sudo dnf install unixODBC-devel
```

On Windows:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=yourserver.yourcompany.com;DATABASE=yourdb;UID=user;PWD=password')
```

On Linux:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=yourserver.yourcompany.com;PORT=1433;DATABASE=yourdb;UID=user;PWD=password;TDS_VERSION=7.2')
```

Comment: Hi Flipper!thanks for the commands. I'm using Git Bash for windows. Can you please suggest how do i do this. One more thing is i'm able to install pyodbc package locally in my system. But when heroku server is trying to install the same package on server side, i'm receiving this error.

Comment: No problem! So, you're using Windows for development and Linux in production on Heroku? This can get tricky (the holy grail is to have your development and production environments be as identical as possible). First I would suggest definitely using a virtualenv, then using pyodbc with the SQL Server driver on Windows / dev, and FreeTDS/unixODBC on Linux / prod Heroku. I'll amend my example above.

Comment: Let me know if it works. I would also highly recommend trying to get your development and production environments at least on the same operating system. Good luck.

Comment: Did anyone get this to work on Heroku?    None of the buildpacks seem to be working now that supported django-pyodbc

Comment: Can you suggest, how do I solve this error when I use MongoDB as a database? The Python code connects to the Mongodb database in the cloud and I get the same error while trying to push into Heroku.Thanks

Comment: If I'm deploying to Heroku would I include the sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev in the Aptfile?

Comment: for osx `brew install unixodbc`

Answer (score 14):

You can add Heroku build pack to preinstall required apt packages first

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt
```

Add `Aptfile` in the your directory root and to the repository as well

```
unixodbc
unixodbc-dev
python-pyodbc
libsqliteodbc
```

It will install everything you need to work with `pyodbc` or `aioodbc` packages from python on Heroku

Comment: Worked like charm! Tried a lot of other buildpacks for odbc but this one actually worked. Thanks for putting it up.

Comment: is Aptfile a file just like the ProcFile that we create  ? (am new to this )

Comment: and how do I do this "Add Aptfile in the your directory root and to the repository as well"

Answer (score 8):

You need the unixODBC devel package. I don't know what distro you are using but you can google it and build from source.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have the required ODBC header files on your machine.
You need to run below command to get g++ installed

```
yum install unixODBC-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are more or less correct; you're missing the `unixodbc-dev[el]` package for your operating system; that's what `pip` needs in order to build `pyodbc` from source.

However, a much easier option is to install `pyodbc` via the system package manager. On Debian/Ubuntu, for example, that would be `apt-get install python-pyodbc`. Since `pyodbc` has a lot of compiled components and interfaces heavily with the UnixODBC OS-level packages, it is probably a better fit for a system package rather than a Python/pip-installed one.

You can still list it as a dependency in your `requirements.txt` files if you're making code for distribution, but it'll usually be easier to install it via the system PM.

Comment: The only problem with installing pyodbc from the OS repositories is that they tend to be *really old* versions of pyodbc. IIRC the Ubuntu repositories install v3.0.7 while the current stable version as I write this is v4.0.21, and 4.x is much better than 3.x at handling Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

I recently saw this error in Heroku. To fix this problem I took the following steps:

1. Add `Apt File` to the root folder, with the following:
   unixodbc
   unixodbc-dev
   python-pyodbc
   libsqliteodbc
2. Commit that
3. Run `heroku buildpacks:clear`
4. Run `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt`
5. Push to Heroku

For me the problem was that I previously installed the buildpack for python, which was not needed. By running `heroku buildpacks:clear`I removed all un-needed buildpacka, then add back the one I needed. So if you do follow these steps be sure to make note of the build packs you need. To view the buildpacks you have run `heroku buildpacks` before following these steps.

Answer (score 0):

RedHat/CentOS:
`dnf install -y unixODBC-devel`
along with unixODBC installation