# Error 1 ERROR: `make' failed when installing sqlsrv

Tags: php, docker, containers, pecl, sqlsrv

I'm trying to install sqlsrv by using the commands from [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases) page. However, when running

```
pecl install sqlsrv-4.2.0preview
```

I get the error: `Error 1 ERROR: 'make' failed`.

I tried :

```
apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential
apt-get install libpcre3-dev 
apt-get install make
```

All of these are installed on the latest version.

I'm running a container using the *php:7.0-apache* image. Running `apachectl -V` returns `Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)`.

Here is the full log output from the command I ran: https://pastebin.com/MYDY3xwU

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I had this exact error.

```
/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/xplat.h:30:17: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sql.h>
```

Apparently the header file its looking for is only in the package unixODBC-devel.

I installed that package and was able to successfully complete the build. `yum install unixODBC-devel`.

Possibly, a better explanation is here. 
[stackoverflow Question # 15447386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447386/sql-h-header-file-missing-though-unixodbc-is-installed)

Comment: The question you linked worked for me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 31):

I had the following error on Ubuntu 18.04 when installing

```
/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/xplat.h:30:10: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory #include <sql.h>
```

Installing the package unixodbc-dev as Matthew Goheen proposed solved the issue

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

try

sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev