# sql.h not found in Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, postgresql

I'm trying to migrate a PostgreSQL db to MySQL using Workbench and I need the PostgreSQL drivers to make the connection.

I'm following [this](http://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/11/set-up-and-configure-postgresql-odbc-drivers-for-the-mysql-workbench-migration-wizard/) post for installing the drivers and I'm having some issues while runing the `make` command:

`./psqlodbc.h:41:10: fatal error: 'sql.h' file not found`

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447386/sql-h-header-file-missing-though-unixodbc-is-installed#15447425) that I need to install `unixodbc-dev` but then I have to uninstall `libiodbc2-dev` which then `make` reports missing `iodbcinst.h` file!

Is there a package where both headers are present? How can I install sql.h manually in the system?

BTW: I'm using Linux Mint.